# Why didn't Boyle made a correlation between V and T of a gas (and similarly between P and T)?

Tags: chemistry

I was just reading about The Gas Laws of Boyle, Charles and Avogadro from a general college book Chemistry (7th edition, Zumdahl&Zumdahl).

 Boyle was the one who discovered a correlation between pressure and volume of a gas.

I was left wondering... 
Why didn't he further studied gas properties at different volume and temperature and/or also between pressure and temperature? The latter is quite similar to his own.

The literature is available on this link: 
https://www.tvusd.k12.ca.us/site/handlers/filedownload.ashx?moduleinstanceid=24457&dataid=8531&FileName=Zumdahl%20Text.pdf

Go to Content --> 5.2 The Gas Laws of Boyle, Charles, and Avogadro (page 181)

Comment: You should include more of your explicit research about all 3 basic gas laws history and timeline. SE sites generally expect explicit compact form of prior research results being added to the question itself.

Comment: On most SE sites, questions that contain phrases like "*a short article*" generally don't fare well.  Good questions include the title of the specific article, where it can be found, and explicit quotations from it. ¶ Otherwise, someone could say "*I read somewhere that …*", and just make it up.  (Note that I'm not implying that you actually did this, only explaining why such indefinite references are usually not well received.)

Comment: @RayButterworth Got it. Will give more details about the source.

Comment: One thing to note is that temperature was only starting to be developed as a consistent concept, so Boyle in the 17th century was limited in that respect. Liquid thermometers were invented around 1600, but the first documented temperature scale was in 1701 and it took decades and several more decades to get to grips with the concept of temperature and how to measure it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the comment by [@Stephan Matthiesen](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/9563/stephan-matthiesen) contains the crucial point (so the credit for the answer should go to him) : -- Boyle's work did not include quantitative temperature effects because he worked in the age before thermometry.

Lack of the techniques of thermometry also limited, in some respects, the work of Boyle's contemporary Newton, and this aspect is mentioned, along with references that also have relevance here, in the following answer:-- [Why is there little scholarship devoted to Book II of Newton's Principia?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/why-is-there-little-scholarship-devoted-to-book-ii-of-newtons-principia/8440#8440) .